# Convert Blob to String with Special Character

Tags: java, blob, data-conversion

I am trying to convert a `blob` variable to string. In DB level, the variable contains XML file with Italian character like

> (è, ò, à e ...)

The code that I already used is as below:

```
   byte[] result = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
   String b = new String(result);
   System.out.println(b);
```

The output cannot resolve the special characters. I guess that is because converting these letters into bytes will eliminate their actual values.

Comment: How is the database column defined?  If it’s `varchar` or `text`, you probably want a [Clob](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Clob.html) rather than a Blob.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually depends how you convert your `String` with non-ASCII characters (Special Characters). You need to specify what `encoding` you are using when converting it from `blob` to `string`.